# rewrite 2 url parameters as directories

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a WordPress site and on one page we have a dynamic vimeo video embed. We use 2 url parameters to embed the video and set the page title.

We would like to rewrite this url so it appears to be directories instead of parameters

> **Current URL:** /video?id=264243188&title=Testing
>
> **Desired URL:** /video/264243188/Testing

Current .htaccess:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /video [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.*)&title=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)  /video/%1/%2? [R=301,NE,L]

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /video?id=$1&title=$2 [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Currently, the URL is not rewritten. IT just shows me the URL parameters

Comment: Hi Ben. I have provided the working solution for your question along with a tester. In case of any issue, do comment or if that solves your problem accept the answer so that other SO users can benefit from the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the below rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /video [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.*)&title=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)  /video/%1/%2? [R=301,NE,L]
```

Working example for the same is at [.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=3233d1e1-c3c9-5c98-99d2-46ae2fa28fc9)

It redirects `http://example.com/video?id=264243188&title=Testing` to `http://example.com/video/264243188/Testing`

And if in case you wanted to convert path to query string you can use the below rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/? video?id=$1&title=$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

[Tester link](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=7ceb2668-a706-56f1-8e6e-4f2e13e5d7ee)

Comment: This isn't working, unfortunately. https://immaculate.co.uk/video?id=264243188&title=Testing

Comment: I have also tried: 
#RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /video?id=$1&title=$2 [L]

Comment: try to add http in the url .The testing tool is limited in functionality due to which it shows it is not working, however in real use case it will work

Comment: adding http or https still does not resolve the issue. Could this be a conflict from WordPress?

Comment: updated the rule with rewrite rule having /video in it. Also updated the tester

Comment: Using that updated code and changing the position (moved it above the WordPress code) has worked however I now see a 404

Comment: I have also updated my question to show current htaccess file

Comment: Updated test url: https://immaculate.co.uk/videoexample?id=264243188&title=Testing (have changed video to videoexample to prevent video from showing 404 as this is used by clients)

Comment: You need to have that video in that particular path. If not it will give 404.

Comment: The video page is a page in wordpress so going to /videoexample will return a page but having the /id/title prevents it from working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173825/discussion-between-ankit-rastogi-and-ben-h).